# The insert data not showing in my database table through postman

Tags: php, json, hosting

I am trying to send data (temperature, humidity and time) from postman through API link for testing my code. I upload my php files in hostinger.com and every time I am trying to send data through postman it gives me OK and no errors but the data not showing in my phpmyadmin database table!

my insert.php code:

```
   <?php

 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

 //Creating Array for JSON response
 $response = array();

 // Check if we got the field from the user
if (isset($_GET['temp']) && isset($_GET['hum']) && isset($_GET['time'])) {

$temp = $_GET['temp'];
$hum = $_GET['hum'];
$time = $_GET['time'];

// Include data base connect class
$filepath = realpath (dirname(__FILE__));
require_once($filepath."/db_connect.php");


// Connecting to database 
$dbo = new DB_CONNECT();

// Fire SQL query to insert data in weather
$result = "INSERT INTO 'climate'('temp', 'hum', 'time') VALUES('$temp', '$hum', '$time')";

// Check for succesfull execution of query
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted 
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "climate successfully created.";

    // Show JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // Failed to insert data in database
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Something has been wrong";

    // Show JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
  // If required parameter is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Parameter(s) are missing. Please check the 
request";

// Show JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
 }
?>
```

and my db_connect.php :

```
<?php

  class DB_CONNECT {
  // Connecting to mysql (phpmyadmin) database


  // Constructor
   function __construct() {
    // Trying to connect to the database
    $this->connect();
   }

   // Destructor
    function __destruct() {
    // Closing the connection to database
    $this->close();
   }

 // Function to connect to the database
  function connect() {

    //importing dbconfig.php file which contains database credentials 
    $filepath = realpath (dirname(__FILE__));

    require_once($filepath."/dbconfig.php");

    // Connecting to mysql (phpmyadmin) database
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost_name, $username, $password);

    // Selecing database

    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}

// Function to close the database
function close() {
    // Closing data base connection
 mysqli_close($con);
 }

}

 ?>
```

and this is my link in postman I am using:

`http://mydomain in hostinger.com/api/insert.php?temp=25&hum=80&time=2019-05- 
    09 08:00:00`

and the result is:

`{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "climate successfully created."
}`

Is there any problem with my code?

Thanks for all

Comment: You don't execute the query. `$result` is just a string. Additionally, your quotes in your SQL query are wrong, e.g. you don't single quote table names or columns names. You should also consider (when looking at how to execute queries) using prepared statements which are available via the PDO and mysqli_* APIs.

Comment: Yea, you need to look at your db_connect & see if there is any execute method, which will be run right after your sql ... ie: $result = "INSERT INTO..."
$dbo->execute($result);

Comment: I made like this `if ($db->query($result) === TRUE) {` but gives me error ` Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT::query()` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually executed the query. `$result` is actually `$query`, and should be passed to your db connection `$dbo`.